# How to mask password exist in json string?

Tags: c#, json, regex, asp.net-core

I am working on .net core c# logging project for my API response.
The output is JSON format with the response contains sensitive info (eg. password)

I am stuck when the response output contains more complex Json structure with an array, whose items are complex objects, each with an "id" property and the keyword denoting the sensitive field, appears as value of that "id" field (see example below).

For the below output, How do I to replace the password value to 'XXXX' using RegEx if the  value of the "id" contains the word 'password' . eg...there are value required to be masked below...

```
{
    "type": "CatalogResourceRequest",
    "description": null,
    "reasons": null,
    "data": {
        "customProperties": [
            {
                
                "data": {
                    "id": "CloneFrom",
                    "is_hidden": false,
                    "value": "TMPLABC"
                }
            },
            {
                
                "data": {
                    "id": "Debug",
                    "is_hidden": false,
                    "value": false
                }
            },
            {
                "data": {
                    "id": "abc_password",
                    "is_hidden": false,
                    "value": "This_Is_Password_To_Be_Masked"
            },

                "data": {
                    "id": "password_of_user1",
                    "is_hidden": false,
                    "value": "This_Is_Password_To_Be_Masked_Also"
                        }           
        }                   
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Serilog to log to JSON, you should be aware this functionality already exists: https://github.com/sandermvanvliet/Serilog.Enrichers.Sensitive

Comment: What is the version of asp.net core? And which serializer did you use,Json.Net or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mask sensitive values in JSON for logging purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37821298/10263) - assuming you are using Json.Net

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working demo by using Json.Net:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("test.json");
    var json = ToObject(data);
     

    return Ok(json);
}
public object ToObject(string json)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
        return null;
    return ToObject(JToken.Parse(json));
}

public object ToObject(JToken token)
{
    switch (token.Type)
    {
        case JTokenType.Object:
            return token.Children<JProperty>()
                        .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name,
                                        prop => ToObject(prop.Value),
                                        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        case JTokenType.Array:
            return token.Select(ToObject).ToList();
        case JTokenType.Null:
            return null;
        default:
            if(((JValue)token).Value.ToString().Contains("password"))
            {
                ViewBag.Id = true;
                return ((JValue)token).Value;
            }
            if(((JProperty)token.Parent).Name== "value" && ViewBag.Id!=null)
            {
                if(ViewBag.Id)
                {
                    ViewBag.Id = false;
                    return "XXXXX";
                }
                return ((JValue)token).Value;
            }
            return ((JValue)token).Value;
    }
}
```

BTW,your provided json is not correct,it should be like below:

```
{
  "type": "CatalogResourceRequest",
  "description": null,
  "reasons": null,
  "data": {
    "customProperties": [
      {

        "data": {
          "id": "CloneFrom",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "value": "TMPLABC"
        }
      },
      {

        "data": {
          "id": "Debug",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "value": false
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "abc_password",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "value": "This_Is_Password_To_Be_Masked"
        }
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "id": "password_of_user1",
          "is_hidden": false,
          "value": "This_Is_Password_To_Be_Masked_Also"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```