# Is there a way to disable handling of DefaultValueAttributes?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a bunch of C# classes, and lots of them utilize the `DefaultValueAttribute` to include UI hints for editing purposes.

I'm serializing instances of these types with `Json.NET` and send them to a `JavaScript` client. To optimize bandwidth, I would like to use `DefaultValueHandling.Ignore` option, BUT in a way that it doesn't take `DefaultValueAttribute`s in account. In other words, I would like to ignore only the *technical* default values `false, 0, null`, but not developer-defined default values.

The reason for it is that the `JavaScript` client has no idea of special, developer-defined default values, so it can handle only the general, above mentioned default values.

Is there any way to turn off using `DefaultValueAttribute`s?

Comment: Removed the [tag:javascript] tag, the question is purely about the C# side of things.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. DefaultValueAttribute is designed to be used by UI designers - it doesn't actually set any default values on the underlying class. It should not be serialized by JsonSerializer - can you add a snippet of the Json stream that gets generated highlighting the issue in the data please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) inheriting from [`DefaultContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) or [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) that resets the [contract default value](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_DefaultValue.htm) for the property back to `default(T)`:

```
public class NoDefaultValueContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    // As of 7.0.1, Json.NET suggests using a static instance for "stateless" contract resolvers, for performance reasons.
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm
    // http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver__ctor_1.htm
    // "Use the parameterless constructor and cache instances of the contract resolver within your application for optimal performance."
    static NoDefaultValueContractResolver instance;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static NoDefaultValueContractResolver() { instance = new NoDefaultValueContractResolver(); }

    public static NoDefaultValueContractResolver Instance { get { return instance; } }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(DefaultValueAttribute), true).Any())
        {
            property.DefaultValue = property.PropertyType.GetDefaultValue();
        }
        return property;
    }
}

public static class TypeExtensions
{
    public static object GetDefaultValue(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        if (!type.IsValueType || Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) != null)
            return null;
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore, ContractResolver = NoDefaultValueContractResolver.Instance };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

By using a custom contract resolver you avoid the need to create converters for each type or member that has a `DefaultValueAttribute` somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that Json.net uses DefaultValueAttribute - it was intended to be used by visual design surfaces, not serializers. I would always set this to Ignore.

If you want to apply the default value prior to serializing you should explicitly set the value just prior to deserialization; you can do this by using reflection on the class instance just before you send it to the serializer. Alternatively you could, as suggested here, [How do you modify the Json serialization of just one field using Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182758/how-do-you-modify-the-json-serialization-of-just-one-field-using-json-net) combine reflection with JsonConvert to intercept the value before it is written to the serializer.